# How to find comments by user_id in group_id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two models (account.js and group.js)
[image]

[image]
[image]
I can find all comments in a group by query:

```js
  Group.findOne({_id:req.body.groupid}).
  populate({
    path: 'comment.user',
  }).
  exec((err,data)=>{
    // console.log(data);
    res.json({
      mss: data,
    });
  });
```

Now I want to find all comments of a user with specific id (user._id) in a specific group (group._id). Any one can help. Thank for advance.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using aggregate, like this:

```
Group.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: req.body.groupid
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            comment: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$comment',
                    as: 'cmnt',
                    cond: { 
                        $eq: [ '$$cmnt.userId', req.body.userId ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

For more info, check docs of [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) operator.

Comment: It return one comment ([{"_id":"5bdd09daf888a42a609bb55b","comment":[{"createdOn":"2018-11-05T03:59:18.215Z","_id":"5bdfc016429f350004852c55","user":"5bdc424c1937f81e78ffae90","content":"Tốt quá rồi\n"}]}]), but i want many comments of user (_id:"5bdc424c1937f81e78ffae90")

Comment: Oh you are right. it returns only one. I updated my answer